# What permissions allow group members to delete files in subdirectories?

Tags: linux, permissions

Let's say I have two users on a Debian GNU/Linux system: `me` and `otheruser`. Both are members of the group `shared-media`. I can create a directory that is writeable by both:

```
$ sudo mkdir /srv/media/test-parent
$ sudo chown root:shared-media /srv/media/test-parent
$ sudo chmod g+w /srv/media/test-parent
$ sudo chmod g+s /srv/media/test-parent
$ ls -dlh /srv/media/test-parent
drwxrwsr-x 2 root shared-media 4.0K Apr 28 19:35 /srv/media/test-parent
```

Now, as `otheruser`, I create a directory and a file within it:

```
$ sudo -u otheruser mkdir /srv/media/test-parent/zztest
$ sudo -u otheruser touch /srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one
```

Unfortunately, this new file cannot be deleted by other members of the group (assume the current user is `me`):

```
$ ll /srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one 
-rw-r--r-- 1 otheruser shared-media 0 Apr 28 19:36 /srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one
$ rm /srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘/srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘/srv/media/test-parent/zztest/one’: Permission denied
```

How do I set up permissions so that `otheruser` only ever creates files that are writeable and deletable by other group members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files themselves are not important; you only need the write permission on the parent directory. To ensure that it's always added, set 'default' ACLs on the base directory:

```
setfacl -m default:group::rwx /srv/media/test-parent
```

This sets a "default" (inherit-only) ACL `group::rwx` (shorthand `g::rwx`), which applies to the owning group (i.e. the group set via chown/chgrp).

But you'll usually want to set an identical "regular" ACL at the same time:

```
setfacl -m g::rwx,d:g::rwx /srv/media/test-parent
```

---

You can simplify this somewhat, by granting access to a specific group directly:

```
setfacl -m g:users:rwx,d:g:users:rwx /srv/blah
```

This makes the 'setgid' bit as well as `chgrp` unnecessary.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea that `setfacl` existed. I presume the new `+` at the end of the directory permissions (`drwxrwsr-x+`) is there to indicate that a different ACL is set for this directory.

Comment: Yes. Also, when an ACL is set, the 'group' column actually shows the _sum_ of all regular ACL entries (except the 'default' ones); the real permissions will be only visible through `getfacl`. Similarly, `chmod g-w` will "mask out" the write permission for all ACL entries at once.